# How can KeyCloak on Kubernetes connect to PostgreSQL?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I am trying to run KeyCloak on Kubernetes using PostgreSQL as a database.

The files I am referring to are on the [peterzandbergen/keycloak-kubernetes](https://github.com/peterzandbergen/keycloak-kubernetes) project on GitHub.

I used `kompose` to generate the `yaml` files, as a staring point, using the files that [jboss](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/tree/master/docker-compose-examples) published.

PostgreSQL is started first using:

```sh
./start-postgres.sh
```

Then I try to start KeyCloak:

```sh
kubectl create -f keycloak-deployment.yaml
```

The KeyCloak pod stops because it cannot connect to the database with the error:

```
10:00:40,652 SEVERE [org.postgresql.Driver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Error in url: jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.4:tcp://10.101.187.192:5432/keycloak
```

The full log can be found on [github](https://github.com/peterzandbergen/keycloak-kubernetes). This is also the place to look at the yaml files that I use to create the deployment and the services.

Comment: This is cool but why not use (and possibly contribute to) the keycloak helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak ? If you don't want to use helm you could still use chart e.g. with https://github.com/blendle/kubecrt

Comment: Missed your suggestion, but agree that helm charts are a better way to use kubernetes efficiently. Was not aware of this chart but will certainly look at it for future use. And thanks for the pointer to kubecrt.

Comment: Peter, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

After some experimenting I found out that using the name **postgres** in the keycloak-deployment.yaml file

```
- env:
    - name: DB_ADDR
      value: postgres
```

messes things up and results in a strange expansion. After replacing this part of the yaml file with:

```
- env:
    - name: DB_ADDR
      value: postgres-keycloak
```

makes it work fine. This also requires changing the postgres-service.yaml file. The new versions of the files are in [github](https://github.com/peterzandbergen/keycloak-kubernetes).

Comment: Alternatively you can set the environment variable `POSTGRES_PORT` to `"5432"` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Played with keycloak a long time ago. Will keep your suggestion in mind when I need to pick it up again. Thanks